# Laravel - Don't allow user to access other user data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel, How can we restrict user to access other user's data?

Do I need to write down code in each and every route functions? or does laravel provides centric approach?

Comment: Might help: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Depends on the situation I would imagine. You can do queries that use the current authenticated user's ID to pull their info only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I don't know your use-case, let suppose you want to protect your user from seeing other user's profile. Now if your show user route is something like

`/users/{id}`

Then just create a middleware let's say `myAuth`

```
class MyAuth
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if(!auth()->check && !auth()->user()->id == request()->get('id'))
    {
      dd("you are not allowed to see this");
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

and include it in your `Http/kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    //Your new middleware
    'myAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyAuth::class,
];
```

And include your routes in this middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'myAuth'], function () {    
    Route::get('user/{id}', function () {
        //Only user with id 1 can see profile of user with id 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way that i know of is to add a scope method to your models. This will guard you on data access level. Bigger systems and complex data structures will require a better solution though. Creating a middleware would provide more flexibility and ability to report would-be hacks.

```
public function scopeMy($query)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
}
// usage
Article::where(...)->my()->get();

// you can pass arguments to method too
public function scopeMy($query, $user)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
}
// usage
Article::where(...)->my($user)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [route group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups) and protect it from some users (or guests).

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

To check for user do something like this:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->id === 17) {
        // $request->user() returns an instance of the authenticated user...
    }
}
```

But usually you want to use group of users:

```
if ($request->user()->isAdmin === true) {
```

Or:

```
if (Auth::user->isAdmin === true) {
```

More on authentication and protecting data [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication).

Comment: This doesn't answer "how to restrict one user from accessing other user's data".

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried to give more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's built-in feature "*Policies*" seems to be a much better and cleaner solution. Please refer [laravel docs on authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) and, as @techfoobar suggested, [this](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1).